# How to swap MySQL table and change auto_increment atomically?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id SERIAL
);
CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id SERIAL
);
```

I want to swap the tables out and set the auto_increment of the new table_a to the MAX(id)+1 of table_b. E.g.

```
SELECT @A:=MAX(id) FROM table_a;
SET @qry = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE table_b AUTO_INCREMENT =', @A+1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
RENAME TABLE table_a TO table_b_tmp, table_b TO table_a, table_b_tmp TO table_a;
```

Unfortunately I can't lock the tables nor do this in a transaction as RENAME TABLE doesn't work on a locked table and ALTER TABLE implicitly commits.

The only solution I can think of to avoid overlapping ids is to set the auto_increment + 50, but as this process is happening frequently I'd rather not have loads of holes in my ids.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think if you're swapping tables over like this on a regular basis you might be better submitting to thedailywtf than stack overflow...

Comment: Thanks, but this is a huge table which can't be dumped efficiently without impacting our live site, hence the need to swap it out. Trust me, I've been down every possible route before arriving here.

Comment: Why are you dumping tables like this?  You'd be much better advised to set up a replicated slave database and take your dumps from that rather than risk your data integrity by mucking with the auto_increment position all the time.

Comment: What type of tables are they?  In particular, are they InnoDB tables?

Comment: I could read from a replica into a new table, however at some point I need to truncate the live table without deleting any records created in the meantime. I could do a DELETE FROM live_table WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dumped_table) however that will take several seconds on a table with several million records.

These are MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the server is not on a version of [MS Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table-problems.html) and you stick with non-transactional tables, you should be able to use table locks and `ALTER TABLE` *`table_name`* `RENAME TO` *`new_table_name`* statements.

```
LOCK TABLES table_a WRITE, table_b WRITE;
SELECT @A:=MAX(id)+1 FROM table_a;
ALTER TABLE table_a RENAME TO table_a_tmp;
LOCK TABLES table_b WRITE, table_a_tmp WRITE;
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE table_b RENAME TO table_a, AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @A;
ALTER TABLE table_a_tmp RENAME TO table_b;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The second lock worries me.  If there are any other pending sessions, will they get a chance at the tables before the lock?  I could also easily be wrong about the above working.  I'm basing the above on the pages below about locks, transactions and ALTER statements.

My other thought is you could create a [MERGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) table for inserts, updating the merge method to FIRST or LAST instead of (along with?) swapping the tables.  Would that work?

- [12.1.7. ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)
- [B.1.7.1. Problems with ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table-problems.html)
- [12.4.3. Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html)
- [12.4.5.1. Interaction of Table Locking and Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO implicitly releases any locks so this doesn't work.

However, I hadn't considered MERGE table idea. I think this could work. I'll try it out and post my results. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ALTER TABLE unlocks transactional tables or under MS Windows.  It should work with MyISAM tables.  That's why I asked about the table type earlier (and included the caveat about MS Windows).